# Html Data parsing issues in nokogiri

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I am having one html file having plain html

I am using **ruby 1.8.7**
I need to take PO number & Tracking no . In which some Tracking no are missing i need to put 'nil' in that case.

But still not able to get the solution properly.

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>***NOTE*** <br> ITems<br><br>
    Invoice Number : [982157] PO Number : [7894562] <br>Shipped To:<br>HOHNE<br> TROXLER RD<br><br>India<br>
    Invoice Number : [982157] PO Number : [7894562] <br>Shipped To:<br>HOHNE<br><br><br>
    <br>
    Invoice Number : [982157] PO Number : [7894562] <br>Shipped To:<br>HOHNE<br>TROXLER RD<br><br>India<br><br>Shipped Via : UPS    Track It : <a href= ab.com> 1Z2559690357791340</a><br><font face="COURIER" size="2" color="black"><br>
    <br>
    Invoice Number : [982157] PO Number : [7894562] <br>Shipped To:<br>HOHNE<br>TROXLER RD<br><br>India<br>
    <br>
    Invoice Number : [982157] PO Number : [7894562] <br>Shipped To:<br>HOHNE<br> TROXLER RD<br><br>India<br><br>Shipped Via : UPS    Track It : <a href= ab.com> 1Z2559690357791340</a><br><font face="COURIER" size="2" color="black"><br>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am having code like

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'nokogiri'   
require 'open-uri'

PAGE_URL = "a.html"

page = Nokogiri::HTML(open(PAGE_URL))
    data = page.css("body").text

    po_numbers = data.scan(/Invoice Number : \[\d+\] PO Number : \[(\d+)\]/).flatten
    tracking_numbers = page.css("a").text.split

    [["PO Number", "Tracking Number"]].concat(po_numbers.zip(tracking_numbers))
 puts po_numbers
 puts tracking_numbers


=> po_numbers = ["7894562", "7894562", "7894562","7894562","7894562"]
=> tracking_numbers = ["1Z2559690357791340", "1Z2559690357791340"]

=> po_numbers.zip(tracking_numbers)
=> [["7894562", "1Z2559691257791340"], ["7894562", "1Z2559690357791340"], ["7894562", "1Z2559690357791340"],["7894562","nil"],["7894562,nil "]]

What i want is 
=> [["7894562", "1Z2559691257791340"], ["7894562", "nil"], ["7894562", "1Z2559690357791340"],["7894562","nil"],["7894562,1Z2559690357791340 "]]
```

Comment: It just dummy data. Need to work on nil value solution

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `Hash` in saving your `po_numbers` and `tracking_numbers`
So you can associate the `po_numbers` with your `tracking_numbers`

Comment: how to make that thing like po_numbers.each_with_index do |elm, index| 
  p "PO Number: #{elm}, Tracking Number: #{tracking_numbers[index]}"
end

Comment: Sorry, it seems that your data has many duplicates. I thought it was unique. In this case, Hash will not work as what you intend. I don't understand why you would like to display `[["7894562", "1Z2559691257791340"], ["7894562", "nil"], ["7894562", "1Z2559690357791340"],["7894562","nil"],["7894562,1Z2559690357791340 "]]` where you can just do : `[["7894562", "1Z2559691257791340"]]` since everything is the same